# Should I be validating before outputting from DB

Tags: php, mysqli

If I am outputting an email address from the Database. Or anything that requires specific input. Should I be running a filter_var() over it before displaying it on the page.

```
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $validated = filter_var($rows['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    if ($validated) {
        echo $validated;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want an email address then you should validate that it is an email address before inserting into the database.  Then maybe `htmlentities()` before displaying.

Comment: But if I am dealing with data that is already there..not inserting

Comment: Try using a template framework like Twig(https://twig.symfony.com/) which dos a lot of the front end filtering and escaping.  It also allows more separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0):

It is best practice to always escape when printing to screen from anywhere. Frameworks like laravel have this as a default behavior.

Comment: So validate the email with filter_var and htmlentities?